# Create SWT table that allows focus and edit on a cell

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I need to create a table that supports:

- focus on a cell
- edit the cell

I found some example using `TreeViewer` in JFace [here](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/plain/examples/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/viewers/Snippet066TableViewerWithLabelDecorator.java) and to add focus on cell [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/677266/).

However it doesn't work. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Update: It works combining the code in the links I put above, but changed the parameters when creating the `TreeViewer` as below:

```
TableViewer v = new TableViewer(shell,
    SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
```

The next problem would be the data displayed. Here we have a class `Person` which holds: id, first name, last name and each column displays these infos.
I need to actually display my data (same data type) in all the columns.

Comment: [_"TableEditor - edit the text of a table item (in place)"_ example](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet88.java), [list of SWT and JFace snippets](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/) with [_TableEditor_ section](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/#tableeditor).